# How can I force an array of scripts to load in sequential order?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, getscript

I am building a single-page web application and each "widget" may require one or more JavaScript or jQuery libraries. Some of those scripts may depend on other scripts, but if I just create a series of `$.getScript` calls, they may load out of order. How can I force that the scripts are loaded in order, i.e. that the process waits for script 1 to download before requesting script 2, etc.?

Comment: You are describing the functionality of javascript dependency management libraries like require.js.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method on the array of script names.

Here is an example of this approach:

```
// Load Script and return promise
function loadScript(script) {
  return $.getScript(script);
}
/**
 * Load list of scripts
 */
function loadScripts(scripts) {
  // Reduce, causes sequenctial order of execution
  return scripts.reduce(function(cur, next){
    // When promise is complete, return next promise (loadScript)
    return cur.then(function(){
      console.log(next);
      // Load the next script and return promise
      return loadScript(next);
    });
  }, $().promise() /* First promise is an empty promise */); 
}
```

([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xonobe/1/edit?html,js,console))

Or in short:

```
function loadScripts(scripts) {
    return scripts.reduce(function(cur, next){ 
        return cur.then($.getScript.bind($, next));
    }, $.when());
}
loadScripts(["./1.js","./2.js","./3.js").then(function(){ // example usage
    // all done here
});
```

Comment: Your scenario sounds pretty crazy though, I wouldn't really recommend loading scripts dynamically and forcing an order. It sounds like a maintenance and debugging nightmare.

Comment: Out of all the answers here, this is definitely the cleanest.

Answer (score 0):

This function accepts an array of URIs to scripts and loads them in order, returning a jQuery promise that will resolve when the last script in the set has loaded.

```
$.load_scripts_sequentially = function (scripts) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();
    var load_script = function (index) {
        var scripts = this;
        if (index > scripts.length - 1) {
            deferred.resolve();
            return;
        }
        $.getScript(scripts[index])
            .done($.proxy(function () {
                load_script.call(this.scripts, this.index + 1);
            }, {scripts: scripts, index: index}))
            .fail($.proxy(function () {
                console && console.error('Failed to load script: ' + this.scripts[this.index], arguments);
                deferred.reject();
            }, {scripts: scripts, index: index}));
    };
    load_script.call(scripts, 0);
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Example usage:

```
$.load_scripts_sequentially(['1.js', '2.js', '3.js']).done(function () {
    console && console.info('All scripts done loading!');
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a deferred here since you've effectively implemented the asynchronous semaphore yourself. `$.getScript` already returns a promise which chains.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the async library to ensure all the libraries are loaded in order.
https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries

Alternatively, as one other user pointed out, you can use require.js